# Socket disconnecting with ping timeout and transport close when multiple connections

Tags: node.js, angular, socket.io

We are working with mean stack, angular 4 and express,
In server side socket.io used and in frontend ng-socket-io used
Frontend code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Socket, SocketIoModule } from 'ng-socket-io';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

export interface Message {
    author: string,
    message: string
}

@Injectable()
export class SocketService {
    constructor( private mysocket : Socket ) {}

    trigger(name,content){
        this.mysocket.emit(name,content);
    }

    getFromEvent() {
      return this.mysocket
          .fromEvent<any>('chatRes')
          .map( data => data );
    }

    insertActive() {
      return this.mysocket
          .fromEvent<any>('insertActive')
          .map( data => data );
    }

    insertStop() {
      return this.mysocket
          .fromEvent<any>('insertStop')
          .map( data => data );
    }

    liveOrderAdd() {
      return this.mysocket
          .fromEvent<any>('liveOrderAdd')
          .map( data => data );
    }

    orderRemoved() {
      return this.mysocket
          .fromEvent<any>('orderRemoved')
          .map( data => data );
    }

    updateLiveOrders() {
      return this.mysocket
          .fromEvent<any>('updateLiveOrders')
          .map( data => data );
    }

    updateActiveOrder() {
      return this.mysocket
          .fromEvent<any>('updateActiveOrder')
          .map( data => data );
    }

    tradeRates() {
      return this.mysocket
          .fromEvent<any>('tradeRates')
          .map( data => data );
    }

    updateStopOrder() {
      return this.mysocket
          .fromEvent<any>('updateStopOrder')
          .map( data => data );
    }

    updateHistory() {
      return this.mysocket
          .fromEvent<any>('updateHistory')
          .map( data => data );
    }

}
```

Backend code is

```
var socketio = require('socket.io');
var chatDb = require('../model/chat.js');
var users = [];
var connections = [];
module.exports.listen = function(app){
  io = socketio.listen(app)
  io.on('connection', function(socket){
    connections.push(socket);

    //Disconnect
    socket.on('disconnect', function(data){
      console.log(data);
      users.splice(users.indexOf(socket.username), 1);
      //updateUsernames();
      connections.splice(connections.indexOf(socket), 1);

      socket.disconnect();
    });

    socket.on('chatMsg',function(det){
      if(det.name && det.message) {
        chatDb.create(det,function(err,resData){
          if(err === null) {
            io.sockets.emit('chatRes',det)
          }
        })
      }
    });

    socket.on('addUser',function(user){
      if(user) {
        users.push(user);
        socket.join(user)
      }
      console.log(users);
    });

    socket.on('connectuser',function(user){
      console.log(user,'testing user');
    });
  });
  return io;
}
```

We need to emit the response from server side and get it from client side this is the important process in our application

Its working fine for 1 or 2 connection(users)

but for number user it disconnected continuesly

with error of ping timeout

when we search in stack overflow somebody said need to put the pingTimeout and pingInterval but the same issue occur

```
var io = require('./server/helpers/socket').listen(server,{'pingInterval': 100000, 'pingTimeout': 600000})
```

we are struggled here anyone help for this appreciated

Awaiting for valuable response Thanks in advance

Comment: I Think you should try and go some steps back. Is “io” a variable? Why don’t you declare it as “var” or “let”? And you want to loop through all your connections and users to remove them from your array? That’s a lot of unessesary work to do. Why do you use “socket.join(user)”? The join() joins the elements of an array into a string? How does that make sense in your case? I think you should try make a simpler example and see if you can connect t multiple users with your angular on the front end - if so you can continue to implement different socket functions and identify where your problem is..

Comment: Io is the variable declare in server.js file we using in that helper file. you can check in next code.
var io = require('./server/helpers/socket').listen(server,{'pingInterval': 100000, 'pingTimeout': 600000})
socket.join for create the room